# XAML Datagrid Cell Select style not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm unable to get a datagrid cell select style to work under certain conditions.

I have the following style:

```
<!--data grid-->
            <Style x:Key="DataGridCellSelect" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DatagridRowSelected}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Using this code within a datagrid works fine like this:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DatagridRowSelected}" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.CellStyle>


However, no matter where I place it, it's not working in this datagrid:



 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridExposureLeft" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Grid.Row="5" 
                    Height="203"
                    IsReadOnly="True" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                    Margin="10,0"
                    SelectionChanged="dataGridExposureLeft_SelectionChanged"
                    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainBackgroundColor}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ExposureID}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Identifier}" Header="Identifier" Width="*"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ExposureImage}">
                                        <Image.Resources>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Image.Resources>
                                    </Image>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Date}" Header="Date" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

The images in the datagrid are so large that they take up the entire visible grid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the exact problem?

Comment: The images in the datagrid are so large that they take up the entire visible grid.

Comment: where do you use the DataGrid.CellStyle?

Comment: Sorry. I tried it in several different places, but I removed it to continue work.. I've placed it before Datagrid.Resources. After Datagrid.Resources. After Datagrid.Columns. etc.

Comment: ok. you just need understand that the DataGrid.CellStyle is hiding each another style related to the Cell. so that is why your image doesn't take your defined Height. from another hand if you need give a specific effect when your cell is selected you need to retemplate your cell.

Comment: Ilan, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I need to retemplate the cell?